# a counterexample for Uniform Spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, uniform-spaces

Uniform Space is a generalization of metric spaces .

In a uniform space the closure of a singleton $\{x\}$ is the intersection of all neighborhoods of $x$.

Find an infinite topological space such that

- it is not a uniform space.
- the closure of any singleton $\{x\}$ is the intersection of all neighborhoods of $x$.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: A topological space is uniformizable if and only if it is completely regular, so you need to find a space that is not completely regular. On the other hand, if $X$ is a Hausdorff space and $x\in X$, then $\{x\}$ is the intersection of the neighborhoods of $x$. (Why?) Thus, it suffices to find a Hausdorff space that is not completely regular, and there are many examples of those; references to two are given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/292991/12042). [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89673/12042) has an example of a Hausdorff space that is not even regular.